# Abelian groups whose automorphism group is a $p$ group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, p-groups

$\def\Aut{\operatorname{Aut}}$
Let $G$ be a finite abelian group such that $\Aut(G)$ is an $p$ group ,that is, $|\Aut(G)|=p^n$ . Then can we determine the cyclic decomposition of $G$ or at least the order of $G$ ?

Comment: The results in http://www.msri.org/people/members/chillar/files/autabeliangrps.pdf should answer this more or less directly.

Comment: Someone should definitely doublecheck this but using theorem 4.1 there I found $G\cong C_{q_1}\times\dots\times C_{q_n} \times C_{p_1} \times \dots \times C_{p_\ell}$ where $q_i$ are distinct powers of $2$ and the $p_i$ are distinct fermat primes.

Comment: Note: using $p$-Sylows, it is easy to check that if $G$ is an arbitrary finite group (possibly non-abelian) such that $Aut(G)$ is a $p$-group, then $G$ is a direct product $H\times K$, where $H$ is abelian of order prime with $p$ and $K$ is a $p$-group. Indeed, $G$ mod its center $Z(G)$ is a $p$-group; define $K$ as a $p$-Sylow of $G$ and $H$ as the maximal subgroup of $Z(G)$ of order prime to $p$.